# React-select not displaying input when modifying value prop using state hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Ive been trying to make a dynamic input field(more input options appear on user input) with react-select, the input gets displayed when I'm not modifying value prop using state variables, but when I modify value prop using state hooks it is not displaying anything.

Here is the code snippet for without hooks which displays output just fine

```
import React,{useState} from "react"
import CreatableSelect from 'react-select/creatable';


export default function DynamicInput(){
const [val,setVal] = useState([])


const options = [
  { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
  { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
  { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
]



    const handleAdd=()=>{
        const tempVal = [...val,[]]
        
        setVal(tempVal)
    }
    
    const handleDel=(indx)=>{
        const deleteVal = [...val]
        
        deleteVal.splice(indx,1);
        
        setVal(deleteVal);
        
        
    }



return (

<div>

    
    <button onClick={()=>handleAdd()}>Add</button>
    {val.map((data,indx)=>{
        return(
                <div key = {indx}>
                                <CreatableSelect isClearable options={options} placeholder="Placeholder" } />
                <button onClick = {()=>handleDel(indx)}>X</button>
                
                </div>
              )
            })
    }

</div>

);
}
```

Now I tried to use hooks to handle the input hooks.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import CreatableSelect from "react-select/creatable";

export function DynamicInputwHooks() {
  const [val, setVal] = useState([]);
  const [selectedOp, setSelectedOp] = useState([]);
  const options = [
    { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
    { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
    { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" }
  ];
  const handleAdd = () => {
    const tempVal = [...val, []];
    const tempSel = [...selectedOp, []];
    setSelectedOp(tempSel);
    setVal(tempVal);
  };
  const handleSelection = (v, indx) => {
    const tempSel = [...selectedOp];
    tempSel[indx] = v.value;
    setSelectedOp(tempSel);
  };
  const handleDel = (indx) => {
    const deleteVal = [...val];
    const deletesel = [...selectedOp];
    deleteVal.splice(indx, 1);
    deletesel.splice(indx, 1);
    setVal(deleteVal);
    setSelectedOp(deletesel);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => handleAdd()}>Add</button>
      {val.map((data, indx) => {
        return (
          <div key={indx}>
            <CreatableSelect
              isClearable
              options={options}
              placeholder={"Placeholder"}
              value={selectedOp[indx]}
              onChange={(e) => handleSelection(e, indx)}
            />
            <button onClick={() => handleDel(indx)}>X</button>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I also added an input box with the same value and it displays value accordingly.
(I am unable to embed code using sandbox but this is the link : https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-darwin-s3ztee?file=/src/App.js)

Upon using inspect element I found that when not using handling value there is an additional div as compared to when modifying value.
When not handling value prop
[The single value div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdQcG.png)

when handling value prop
[No single value div gets created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nch2y.png)

I cannot use useRef as there can be multiple inputs.

any help how to solve this would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after some more searching I found this sandbox example that helps solve the problem
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-set-value-example-d21pt?file=/src/App.js
while this works for react-select but using it for react-select creatable requires appending to the options based on **isNew** prop of input when creating a new option.